# Does web framework do it all?

Tags: django, reactjs, frameworks, zurb-foundation

I would like to know of what web framework is responsible off.

I'm thinking to start a web app project, so I'm digging what frameworks should I use. So for HTML/CSS I'm thinking of **Foundation framework**, for JS I have chose to use **React framework**.

For a backend I have chosen to use **Django framework**, and it says that Django is a web framework. Will I be able to implement Foundation and React to django, or django will take care off all those aspects?

Comment: In essence, it is responsible to retrieve HTTP requests, and return HTTP answers, that's basically it.

Comment: *Web* framework takes care of *web*. Does this clarify something? I guess it doesn't. 'web framework' is umbrella term and doesn't have any special meaning. Also, if you're considering React *JS* framework, Django is *Python* framework. They are apples and oranges. The question is incorrect.

Comment: to answer your question, you can use Django as a backend to create a rest api for react to consume using django-rest-framework. Or you can also use Django to do the whole thing(back-end and front-end), since you can create templates that contain html and css.
and what you can also do is having a react project inside a django app  
https://github.com/vintasoftware/django-react-boilerplate/

Comment: What path do you recommend? 
Use Django as an API for React; 
Use Django for front and back developement; 
Use React inside Django; ?